# Filebeat's GCP Module keep getting hash config error

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, filebeat

I am currently trying to forward GCP's Cloud Logging to Filebeat to be forwarded to Elasticsearch following this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/exporting-stackdriver-logging-elasticsearch) with the GCP module settings on filebeat according to this [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-gcp.html)

Currently I am only trying to forward audit logs so my `gcp.yml` module is as follows

```
- module: gcp
  vpcflow:
    enabled: false
    var.project_id: my-gcp-project-id
    var.topic: gcp-vpc-flowlogs
    var.subscription_name: filebeat-gcp-vpc-flowlogs-sub
    var.credentials_file: ${path.config}/gcp-service-account-xyz.json
    #var.internal_networks: [ "private" ]

  firewall:
    enabled: false
    var.project_id: my-gcp-project-id
    var.topic: gcp-vpc-firewall
    var.subscription_name: filebeat-gcp-firewall-sub
    var.credentials_file: ${path.config}/gcp-service-account-xyz.json
    #var.internal_networks: [ "private" ]

  audit:
    enabled: true
    var.project_id: <my prod name>
    var.topic: sample_topic
    var.subscription_name: filebeat-gcp-audit
    var.credentials_file: ${path.config}/<something>.<something>
```

When I run `sudo filebeat setup` I keep getting this error

```
2021-05-21T09:02:25.232Z    ERROR   cfgfile/reload.go:258   Error loading configuration files: 1 error: Unable to hash given config: missing field accessing '0.firewall' (source:'/etc/filebeat/modules.d/gcp.yml')
```

Although I can start the service, but I don't seem to see any logs forwarded from GCP's Cloud Logging pub/sub topic to elastic search.

Help or tips on best practice too would be appreciated.

#### Update

If I were to follow the [docs in here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/current/monitor-gcp.html#_step_5_configure_filebeat_google_cloud_module), it would give me the same error but in `audit`

Comment: Which option from the guide you have been used (Option 1 or Option 2)? Is this your whole configuration file? What happens when you use `true` in the firewall section?

Comment: @PjoterS If I were to put `true` in firewall, then it would get the same error but it will be on `0.vpcflow`. And for option 1 and 2 I'm kinda unclear which one you're asking but for Filebeat to ES auth I skipped it as I'm not using the auth system, and I don't use logstash

Comment: I am also getting the same error.